# Only two out of three AdSense ads appear

Tags: javascript, adsense

**UPDATE:** Please disregard this question. The referred domain name I have purposefully expire and no longer maintaining.

---

folks. I have been very puzzled with 'the case of the missing AdSense ad' I'm experiencing.

On my blog, I have 3 ad locations: Top banner (responsive), bottom banner (responsive), and in sidebar (250x250).

The banner ads appear properly.

The sidebar ad... it once *did* appear, but now it no longer appears. And the 'backup ad' I've configured for it likewise does not appear.

Here's a sample page: http://pandu.poluan.info/blog/20131030-15/xenserver-6-2-0-stability-dell-r815/

The sidebar ad should be in the grey-ish box on lower right... but it's blank.

Can someone check the source of the page and tell me where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: It maybe because your pages have very little content, there aren't enough suitable keywords to generate relevant ads for all your units.

Comment: @RoyMJ the problem is, at first, the ad on the sidebar did appear. Then I tweak the page's layout to add the banner ads, and the ad on the sidebar no longer appears. Plus, as per Google's guideline, I've prepared a 'backup ad' in case there's no relevant ad suitable for the sidebar space, it doesn't appear either.

Comment: @KenSharp I don't know... I have decided that maintaining my own domain is too much work so I have let the domain expire.

Answer (score 0):

1.I investigate Your issue but I can't find any code regrading ads on your page 
2.I found one jquery error in console on your website "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" so use "Jquery" instant of "$" for fixing issue

Comment: the sidebar-ad code is on line 372 on that page. You can do a quick search for "pepoluan pages - sidebar". I'll see what I can do about the Jquery error, since the code was not originally mine; I just modified the code for the **Chyrp** blogging engine.

Comment: I've fixed the "$ is not defined" error; apparently the .twig file for the theme I'm using had the "jquery.min.js" line transposed with the "theme.js.php" line. However, the sidebar ad (either Google's or my own 'backup ad') still doesn't appear.